# Can I reverse this motor?

Tags: dc-motor

For a pet project I want to run a motor and also be able to reverse the direction. I found [this motor](http://www.banggood.com/400W-DC-12V-48V-12000rpm-Air-Cooled-Spindle-Motor-Engraving-Milling-p-1051176.html) and pasted the information table below. As far as I know a DC motor needs to be brushed for it to be able to reverse the direction, but I can't find if this motor is brushed or brushless.

Am I missing something? Does anybody know if I will be able to reverse this motor? All tips are welcome!

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to its description and my experience buying in Banggood it IS a brushed motor, so reversing its direction is possible (although DC motors lose a bit of efficiency when their direction is reversed).

Comment: Thanks! I didn't know DC motors lose efficiency when reversed. Do they lose a lot, or is it less than say 10%?

Comment: Depends on the quality of the motor, but as far as I used them I've never seen a motor loose more than 5% of efficiency

Comment: Actually, there is no reason you should see any change in efficiency. Consider that the motor manufacturer has no way to tell which direction will be used, so there is on way for them to optimize for a certain direction. In other words, I'm fairly certain that your statement is just wrong.

Comment: @WhatRoughBeast, actually Sir, brush type motors almost always run at slightly different speed and/or efficiency in different directions for a couple reasons. First of all is timing advance - the exact angle of the brushes relative to the field magnets may be optimized for one direction. Secondly, on a lot of cheap motors like above, the brushes are mounted on spring loaded contacts coming from the side - so there will be more pressure in one direction of turning but also more brush bouncing. But it's usually insignificant.

Comment: @JesseGordon have used brushed DC motors in CNC machines for many years. The ones I've used worked virtually identically in both directions because such symmetry is more or less a requirement.

Answer (score 0):

To check if it a brushed motor, if there is no brush caps on the outside, just put a meter across it. On ohms, it will show a very low resistance, and on volts, if you turn turn the shaft, you will see a + or - voltage. If so, just reverse the polarity on the input. If you don't have a meter, put a short across it and it will be hard to turn. If you put a torch globe across it, you will be able to light it if you turn the shaft quickly. If it is electronically commutated, you may still get a voltage produced when you spin the shaft, with the motor acting like an alternator and the components in the IC acting as a full wave bridge rectifier, but  the polarity will be normal irrespective of which way you turn the shaft.

Answer (score 0):

It's a brushed motor. Brushless motors have more than 2 wires - at least 3 - unless they have the motor driver built in but this obviously doesn't because it would be a circuit board with heatsinks and it would show.